# Jquery Fancybox-media prev and next buttons need three clicks to work

Tags: fancybox-2

I know there must be a conflict somewhere in  jquery scripts that I have  going on in my page. Essentially, the problem is I am using Fancybox 2 and calling up vimeo videos using the fancybox media commands:

```
$(".fancybox-media")
        .fancybox({
             beforeLoad: function() {
        var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

        if (id) {
            el = $('#' + id);

            if (el.length) {
                this.title = el.html();
                  }
              }
          },
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        padding: 0,
        arrows: true,
        helpers : {
            media : {},
            buttons: {},
            title   : {
                type: 'inside'
            },
        overlay : {
        css : { 'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95)'}},
    }
});
```

It all works fine except for the previous and next buttons require three clicks before they will engage and advance to the next video.

Anyone have an idea why that is? Do I need to add a specific target name on the buttons?
Right now they are engaged by the

```
   helpers : {
            media : {},
            buttons: {},...
```

But should I add something like

```
 buttons: {'#itemname'},
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got a working sample?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is behind a client's passworded gateway. I'll see if I can create a fiddle of it, although it's pretty complex. I know I'm just over looking one small thing and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: maybe is related to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/17825977/1055987 who knows.