# Picture is shown 3 times on fancybox Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use this plugin: http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/

This is the url: http://estebanescoo.com.ar/fotografia.php

when you clic on any photo, and you press 'next' or 'previous' you'll notice each photo is shown 3 times, why is that?

I'll appreciate your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is because you missed to close properly your `<a>` tags :

You have this html :

```
<div class="thumb"><a class="fancybox" ...><img src="{}"></div>
<div class="thumb"><a class="fancybox" ...><img src="{}"></div>
...etc.
```

but it should look more like :

```
<div class="thumb"><a class="fancybox" ...><img src="{}"></a></div>
<div class="thumb"><a class="fancybox" ...><img src="{}"></a></div>
...etc.
```

Validating your document helps to detect this type of syntax mistakes.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jX3Vc/)**

Comment: @GuillermoDelicia : de nada, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

its because in html the images and url are generating three times check your html or check your php file